# Discretize frequency of words that follow zipfian distribution

Tags: continuous-data, discrete-data, binary-data, zipf, feature-engineering

How could I discretize the frequency of words found in a corpus that follow a zipfian distribution? Are there standard methods? It should create bins of exponential-increasing size.

My goal is to convert this continuous real frequency into multiple bins to create binary features in Conditional Random Fields (CRFs). I would like to be able to easily define how many bins/divisions I want, to be more or less precise as desired.

For clarification, I have generated a list ordered by `freq` that gives me the frequency and cumulative frequency of each word in a studied corpus:

```
#1 word1 freq1 cumFreq1
#2 word2 freq2 cumFreq2
#3 ...
```

Then when generating features in a training set, for every wordx I want to assign it the feature-bin it belongs to or a `NOT_IN_DICTIONARY` label if the wordx was never found in the studied corpus. I want to create bins-labels so that they group words by similar frequency.

Comment: What is a "[CRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRF)"? Critical repetition frequency?  Conditional random field?  Cardiovascular risk factor?  Capital recovery factor?  Case report form?  Etc... .  What is the reason for creating "binary features"?

Comment: @whuber you're right, edited. My primary reason is simply practical, the framework I'm using for conditional random fields, Mallet, has an overall better support for binary features, and in any case CRFs are typically used with this type of features. Also, binary features allow for more divergence in weights, simply more weights, that for log-linear models like CRFs may be beneficial.

Comment: If the variable is continuous, how does it follow a Zipf distribution?

Comment: "Words" are mentioned; so it would seem that this isn't a continuous thing.  Are you trying to take a vector that represents the counts of all the unique words from some corpus that are present in a specific document and then change these vectors into a vector of booleans somehow?

Comment: I wrote more info in the description for clarification. @jbowman yes, I guess you're right, I try to be more correct in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

So far my solution is the following: set constant `cumulativeFrequencyBinSize` size for the bins, `(1)` fill current bin till reached quota `(currentCumulativeFreq + cumulativeFreqBinSize)`, `(2)` repeat `1` for next bin and so until all words are included. This allows to easily define the number of bins since the total cumulative frequency is of course 1 and bins effectively have an exponential-increasing size in number of words (constant in cumulative frequency)

Comment: When you create bins that depend so intimately on the data, you *cannot* treat them in the way you would bins that were developed independently of the data.  I begin to wonder: are you binning in order to discretize the data for further analysis or are you attempting to *cluster* the data?

Comment: I'm binning them in order to discretize the data for further analysis. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see a problem with my current method. Basically what I'm doing is assigning to my words labels that depend on their frequency within a corpus. Since I don't want to use directly the frequency I discretize this frequency and group those words that appear similarly equally often together with the same label. Then these features-labels-bins can have different weights that can be trained independently, instead of having just one weight that correlates directly to the frequency.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the further analysis.  In general, creating bins based on the data--especially in such a close, intimate fashion--leads to exaggerated significance in formal testing and to overfitting for exploration or prediction.  I'm not saying it's bad, but want to point out that it's a (subtle) pitfall to be wary of and to correct.

Comment: I see. Being specific, I'm doing named entity recognition. The corpus that I use to collect these frequencies has millions of documents, enough to have valid frequencies. Then I also have a big list of multi-token names of the entities I want to recognize, for which I also collect statistics. I discretize the frequencies of both dictionaries and then I combine them so that in total I have `(num_bins_global_corpus) x (num_bins_names)` The idea behind is that basically words that appear few times in the whole corpus but many times in the names are important for the recognition of these entities.

Comment: Overall, this feature, their combination, is just one within millions of features, so I guess I'm not overfitting.